# Running background tasks in React Native in short intervals

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I'm trying to build a time lapse camera that captures images even when the screen is off (battery non-optimised). Ideally for both iOS and Android, but I'm working with Android at the moment. I've poked around [react-native-background-job](https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job) and [react-native-background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task), but they all restrict the intervals to be >15 minutes on Android. Is there a good way to fire tasks in smaller intervals?

Comment: Have you found the solution? @john-m

Comment: @xruptronics No, I don't think there is one.